# Find match in second column using possible non-unique value in first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, excel-match

I have two columns of data: `SubID` (`Column A`) and `Gender` (`Column B`).  The `SubID` can be listed several times in `Column A`.  I would like to create a new column (`Column C`) that lists the `Gender` with every instance that the `SubID` occurs in `Column A`.

To do this I need to lookup/match the `Gender` in `Column B` with the `SubID` in `Column A`, while only reporting the `Gender` in `Column C` and without returning a blank cell or just a repeat of `Column B`.

I have used `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH` without any real luck.  I'm sure something in my formula is set up incorrectly.

Below is an example of my data and some of the formulas I have tried.

[image: sample]

`=IF(B2=".",INDEX($A$2:$B$6081,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$6081,0),2),INDEX($A$2:$B$6081,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$6081,0),2))`

`=IF(B3=".",(IF($A$2:$A$6081=$B$2:$B$6105,$B$2:$B$6081,"x")))`

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$6081,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6081=A4,ROW($A$2:$A$6081)),1),2)),"",INDEX($A$2:$B$6081,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$6081=A4,ROW($A$2:$A$6081)),1),2))`

Comment: Please show some test data and expected outcome, as it will help use understand better.  Also show what formulas you have tried, again to help us understand.

Comment: If column A is the subject ID and column B is the gender, why are multiple instances of the subject ID possible? Please reword question and/or add images of spreadsheet to clarify.

Comment: The link you posted is inaccessible due to permissions lock.

Comment: I think I fixed it.  Try again.

Comment: A few notes: your first formula above is redundant. It's asking Excel to do the same formula whether `B2=" . "` is TRUE or FALSE. Also, I agree with @ImaginaryHuman072889 when they ask how multiple instances of the `SubID` are possible. For example, won't **A1**'s `Gender` always return the same, and therefore for any row in `Column C` won't the answer be the value in the same row of `Column B`?

Comment: This is a small subset from a very large data set.  The subID are moved across multiple locations, however, the gender was only reported on the initial location.  I need the gender to be across all locations.